# Find sub task of Story that has an Epic Link

Tags: jql

I'm trying to find a list of sub-tasks related to a parent that has an Epic Link.

something like the following

project = PRJLPR AND issuetype in (Story, "Development Sub-task") AND Epic Link = "Allow Login" ORDER BY "Epic Link"

is this possible?

thanks

Chris